# How to rolling sum for specific intervals in time series data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have time series data and I want to create another column that sums the value for each day. For example:

```
df
timestamp             val    sum
2022-10-10 00:00:00   50      50
2022-10-10 00:01:00   10      60
2022-10-10 00:02:00   20      80
...
2022-10-10 23:59:00   10     2300
2022-10-11 00:00:00   20      20
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) per dates:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.date)['val'].cumsum()
```